# How do I store a state that I have set to use in other components (so that I can then send that component's value to a database)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase

I'm trying to store the this.state.url that I'm getting back from firebase after I successfully store an image to firebase. Right now now I am console logging the response and am able to render the response url as an image on the page. I want to be able to some how store that url as a string so that I can send it to a separate SQL database I have set up. Thanks for your help ! :)

I must not understand the way props work because I created another prop but must be unsuccessfully linked them. I really just need the string to be sent to the SQL database via axios so if there is a way to do that in this component that would be great - or if the only way to do it is via another component then that works too. Right now Im trying to set the this.state.url as a const so that I can refer to it in another component and it doesnt seem to be working.

````
import {storage} from '../firebase';


class ImageUpload extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      image: null,
      url: '',
      progress: 0
    }
    this.handleChange = this
      .handleChange
      .bind(this);
      this.handleUpload = this.handleUpload.bind(this);
  }
  handleChange = e => {
    if (e.target.files[0]) {
      const image = e.target.files[0];
      this.setState(() => ({image}));
    }
  }
  handleUpload = () => {
      const {image} = this.state;
      const uploadTask = storage.ref(`images/${image.name}`).put(image);
      uploadTask.on('state_changed', 
      (snapshot) => {
        // progrss function ....
        const progress = Math.round((snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100);
        this.setState({progress});
      }, 
      (error) => {
           // error function ....
        console.log(error);
      }, 
    () => {
        // complete function ....
        storage.ref('images').child(image.name).getDownloadURL().then(url => {
            console.log(url);
            this.setState({url});
        })
    });
  }


  render() {
    const style = {
      height: '100vh',
      display: 'flex',
      flexDirection: 'column',
      alignItems: 'center',
      justifyContent: 'center'
    };
    return (
      <div style={style}>
      <progress value={this.state.progress} max="100"/>
      <br/>
        <input type="file" onChange={this.handleChange}/>
        <button onClick={this.handleUpload}>Upload</button>
        <br/>
        <img UserUpload={this.state.url || 'http://via.placeholder.com/300x300'} alt="Uploaded images" height="300" width="300"/>
      </div>
      // const UserUpload = this.state.url
    )
  }
}

export default ImageUpload;```


Right now I'm just rendering the url via an img src to the page and console.log'ing the url response i get from firebase.

I am super thankful for any help you all give - I'm extremely new to coding and appreciate any help I can get!
````

Comment: Are you using redux?

Comment: You can add the `axios` call inside the `getDownloadURL().then(...)` callback function.

Comment: @Titus I thought so - but this is going to go into a sign up modal on the browser page and ideally I don't want the user to have to hit a upload button - want it to happen on the submit button and get sent with the rest of the regular POST command. I did it separately in this component because I thought it would have weird async problems. Thank you for you help!

Comment: @gergana I'm sorry for my ignorance - I'm not sure what redux is - but I don't believe so? Thanks for responding! :)

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to send the image's URL to this component's parent so that component can save it on user action. If that is the case, you could pass a function to this component through props, and call that function when the URL is available so that the parent can save it.

Comment: @Titus Will try that ! Thanks

Comment: If you want to make an API request to save URL to your MYSQL database, then you can simply call a function from inside getDownloadURL().then() function (where you are console.logging the url) and pass url to function and perform the API request. However if you want url to be avialable in other components of your application then you should look into shared services.

Comment: So I would recommend for shared services, in order of increasing learning curve IMHO, would be react context (this reduces component re-usability), then react hooks (this only works for functional components though) and then redux.